# Converting Large HTML to Excel (xlxs) file in an efficient way

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, export-to-excel

I have the following javascript function which needs convert my HTML table to Excel sheet, this is working fine for less data but i have a use case where the HTML table will have more than 400 000 records then my browser is unable to download the file as the browser page is crashing and going into OutOfMemory exception.

```
function exportReportToExcel(id) {
    let table = document.getElementById("table" + id);
    let Name = document.getElementById("FileName" + id).value;
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    var CurrentDateTime = date + ' ' + time;
    FileName = Name.concat(CurrentDateTime);
    TableToExcelTableToExcel.convert(table, {
        name: FileName + `.xlsx`,
        sheet: {
            name: 'sheet 1'
        }
    })
}
```

The one row of HTML table  will be like this, In my case i have 400 000 of this kind.

```
 <tr>
<td>Country</td>
<td>1234</td>
<td>Active</td>
<td>123456</td>
<td>Patients</td>
<td>Drug</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
</tr>
```

Could anyone please suggest an efficient way to write the function

[TabletoExcel method link](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/linways/table-to-excel@v1.0.4/dist/tableToExcel.js)

Comment: Creating an Excel file with that many records on the client side is, frankly, ridiculous. Do it server side.

Comment: Guessing you have 400 000 records, not 40 000 000 000 as it said (also, please don't use "lakh", we're not all from India)